# single sign on using facebook for iPhone application

Tags: iphone, facebook, authentication, single-sign-on

I know that SSO is possible for web application, so I want to is there any possibility to implement single signon using facebook account for iPhone application i.e. if some one has account in the facebook he should be able to login in my iPhone application also using his facebook credentials.
If not facebook then which other social networking sites we can achieve SSO for iPhone application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the facebook userid and other user information using new facebook graph APIs and this userid you can use to create new user in your server because this is a unique id for facebook users. You can get the sample code [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1578/how-to-get-a-user-profile-with-facebooks-new-graph-api-from-your-iphone-app).